# Passing values from one input field to another

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to pass a value from one input field to another input field with vanilla JavaScript. This is the HTML I used:

```
<input type="text" id="input1">
<input type="text" id="input2">
```

When I try to pass it to a paragraph it works, but passing it to a new input field it won't.

Comment: "When I try to pass it to a paragraph it works, but passing it to a new input field it won't." — You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: Mind showing the JavaScript code? It should be as easy as `document.getElementById('input1').value = document.getElementById('input2').value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `input` elements, you should be using the element's `value` property, instead of `innerHTML` like for paragraphs.  Then it becomes as simple as:

```js
var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");

input2.value = input1.value;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1" value="hello">
<input type="text" id="input2">
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is indeed what I needed!

Comment: @dikkeMeeuw Glad this helps! If this answered your question, please consider upvoting/marking as answer. Have a good day!